# Boolean Algebra Simplification of (x'y'+z)'+z+xy+wz

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, demorgans-law

How would you simplify the following? I'm having a bit of trouble with the first part with negation. How would DeMorgan’s Theorem be applied here?

> (x'y'+z)'+z+xy+wz

Please provide answer in detail.

**Update:**

The complete question that I got was to prove that

> (x'y'+z)'+z+xy+wz

equals

> x+y+z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial expression:**

```
(x'y' + z)' + z + xy + wz
```

**Apply DeMorgan's Theorem:**

```
(x'y')'z' + z + xy + wz
```

**Simplify (a'b + a = b + a):**

```
(x'y')' + z + xy + wz
```

**Apply DeMorgan's Theorem:**

```
x + y + z + xy + wz
```

**Rearrange (commutativity/associativity):**

```
x + xy + y + z + wz
```

**Factor:**

```
x(1 + y) + y + z(1 + w)
```

**Simplify (1 + a = 1):**

```
x + y + y + z
```

**Simplify (a + a = a):**

```
x + y + z
```

Comment: Thanks, I had made it to that far but I'm now stuck. The question that I got was:

Prove that **(x'y' + z)' + z + xy + wz** = *x+y+z*

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get all the way there.

Comment: What law does **(a'b + a = b + a)** apply to?

Comment: I do not know its name, if it has one, but you can prove it easily enough via a truth table.